# Redirect to a random index.html file in a directory?

Tags: php, html

How would I go about having a www.example.com/random.php redirect to a random index.html file in the directory www.example.com/pages/? Note that the index.html files are inside folders inside /pages/. Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Well, you make a list of all such pages (automatically or manually) and then use a random number to select one of them. Finally you send a location header to that page.

Comment: please post your any tired code ?

Comment: @arkascha I would do this, however the /pages/ directory will grow later and I don't think updating it manually would be very efficient.

Comment: I wrote "automatically _or_ manually"...

Comment: @Hikmat Sijapati I'm no good at PHP and I have been looking around for a solution similar to mine and haven't found one, so I don't really have any. Sorry.

Comment: @arkascha I don't know how to make it update automatically every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you make a list of all such pages (automatically or manually) and then use a random number to select one of them. Finally you send a location header to that page...

Here is a simple example:

```
<?php
define('FILE_PATH_PATTERN', 'pages/*/index.html');
$indexPages = glob(FILE_PATH_PATTERN);
$targetIndex = rand(0, count($indexPages)-1);
$targetPage = &$indexPages[$targetIndex];
header('Location: ' . $targetPage);
```

The result is a location header getting sent to the client which forwards to the target page `/pages/_some_random_folder_/index.html`.

Note however that this is questionable... Typically when programming php based web applications one does *not* want to publish the internal file system hierarchy (since it is internal). Instead one uses a central router script that responds to *all* incoming requests and only delivers the content read from some internal html markup file.

Comment: Looks promising. Let's only hope they don't come back and say: *"It's not working"*. Edit: v I stand corrected ;-) *woohoo!!*

Comment: Hell yeah, it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: There's a little something, however. Sometimes it redirects to itself, so is there some sort of if statement I can use to make it roll again?

Comment: @EthanElzenaar-Adams For that you'd need find out where it actually redirects to... Cause it certainly does _not_ redirect to itself...

Comment: @EthanElzenaar-Adams Ah, sorry, I see and fixed the issue you _most likely_ experienced. I added a `-1` to the arguments of the `rand()` function call...

Comment: @arkascha That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function get_rand_page(){
     $dirs=array_filter(glob(__DIR__.'/pages/*'), 'is_dir');//get all the directories in that file.
     $rand_dir=$dirs[array_rand($dirs)];//select a random directory name
     return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/pages/".$rand_dir."/index.html";//return random sub-directory as uri

}
```